# Emit event to component when validators are cleared

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have created a custom input component. Its label is displayed when there is a required constraint (computed in OnInit).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `<div *ngIf="isMandatory()">Mandatory</div><input/>`
})
export class CustomInput implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

  mandatory = false;

  constructor(
    @Self()
    @Optional()
    public ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
    super(ngControl);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mandatory  = this.isMandatory();
  }

 public isMandatory(): boolean {
    let mandatory = false;
    if (this.ngControl) {
      const errors = new FormControl('', this.ngControl.control.validator, this.ngControl.control.asyncValidator).errors;
      mandatory = errors?.required;
    }
    return mandatory;
  }


 writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.value = value;
  }

 ...
```

Let's say that the constraint changes. I would like to update the label as the input becomes optional.

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  custominput: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});

// remove required validator => I want to compute the 'mandatory' variable again
this.form.controls.customInput.clearValidators();
this.form.controls.customInput.updateValueAndValidity();
```

How can I update my label (send an event inside my component)? I would like to avoid subscribing to statusChanges.

The only trick I have found is:

```js
  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.value = value;
    this.mandatory  = this.isMandatory();
  }

... 

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      customInput: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });

 
    this.form.controls.customInput.clearValidators();
    // In order to trigger writeValue function
    this.form.controls.customInput.setValue(this.form.controls.customInput.value);
    this.form.controls.customInput.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 0):

ngControl holds the control, so you can use

```
  control.invalid ,control.dirty,control.touched, control.errors
```

More generic approach is to inject controlContainer

```
constructor(@Host() @SkipSelf() @Optional() private controlContainer: ControlContainer)
 public ngOnInit() {
    if (this.controlContainer) {
        this.control = this.controlContainer.control.get(<control name>);
    }
}
```

.html

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched) }"> 
    <input
      ngDefaultControl
      id="{{ id }}"
      placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
      [ngClass]="{
        'ng-dirty ng-invalid': control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched)
      }"
    />
  <div
    class="explain-error"
    *ngIf="control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched)"
  >
    {{ control.errors | format-pipe }}
  </div>
</div>
```